# Add objects to arraylist and read them

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, arraylist

I'm trying to add objects of `DataPerLabel` to my `Arraylist allData`, following the code of `DataPerLabel`:

```
class DataPerLabel
{
    public String labelName;
    public String labelAdress;
    public String dataType;

    public DataPerLabel(String labelName, String labelAdress, String dataType)
    {
        this.labelName = labelName;
        this.labelAdress = labelAdress;
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public String getLabelName()
    {
        return labelName;
    }

    public String getLabelAdress()
    {
        return labelAdress;
    }

    public String getDataType()
    {
        return dataType;
    }
}
```

In the following code I try to add the objects of `DataPerLabel` to my `arraylist`:

```
submitButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    String label = textboxLabel.Text;
    String adress = textboxAdress.Text;
    String dataType = "hey";

    if (buttonsLabelBool.Checked)
    {
        dataType = "Bool";
    }
    else if (buttonsLabelReal.Checked)
    {
        dataType = "Real";
    }
    else if (buttonsLabelInt.Checked)
    {
        dataType = "Int";
    }
    allData.Add(new DataPerLabel(label, adress, dataType));
};
```

And finally I try to read out the `arrayList` by displaying it in a `textbox`, see the following code:

```
private void test()
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(500,500);
    btn.Text = "test";
    btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in allData)
        {
            //Display arraylist per object here
            //Something like : item.getLabelName();
        }
    };
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, hope you can help!

Comment: Well what is going wrong?

Comment: Use `List<DataPerLabel>` instead of `ArrayList`. You can solve the problem by casting `item`, but why cast if you can use `List<T>`.

Comment: Agree with Sinatr. Using `List<T>` allows you to directly access the members of your current item. With `ArrayList` you´d have to cast every item to `DataPerLabel`.

Comment: Visual studio is not giving me an option to do item.getLabelName and gives the error: 
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'getLabelName' and no extension method 'getLabelName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: use List<T> requires no upcasting/downcasting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) stores a list of `System.Object`. You need to cast the object back to `DataPerLabel` as follows:

```
foreach (var item in allData)
{
    ((DataPerLabel)item).getLabelName();
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify the data type in the foreach instead of `var` as  [Jakub Dąbek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7931009/jakub-d%C4%85bek) pointed out in the comment as follows:

```
foreach (DataPerLabel item in allData)
{
    item.getLabelName();
}
```

A better approach would be to use generic list/collection `List<DataPerLabel>` to store the data so that the casting can be avoided.

Comment: You can just do the cast automatically by specifying the type of the variable in `foreach` like `foreach(DataPerLabel item in allData)` even while using `ArrayList`. Nevertheless `List<T>` is just better

Answer (score 1):

Yiu should use a `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`. This way every item in your list has the right type already and you can access the members:

```
foreach (DataPerLabel item in allData)
{
    item.GetLabelItem();
}
```

This assumes `allData` is defined like this:

```
allData = new List<DataPerLabel>();
```

instead of `allData = new ArrayList()`

If you really have to use an `ArrayList` than you should cast your item to the actual type. The code above actually does this allready. However you could also use this:

```
foreach (var item in allData)
{
    ((DataPerLabel)item).GetLabelItem();
}
```