# Access Array List inside a public class

Tags: c#, linq, class

Not the duplicate of 
[Add objects to arraylist and read them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275586/add-objects-to-arraylist-and-read-them)
I could access the data and read them in json format but not in orderItem.PO , etc format. And also my problem is not "How to read".

I have a `List<xmlOrder>` items which contain orders information and their items.
I can access the list like following:

```
    foreach (var order in items)
    {
       string query = "insert into Orders values ('" + order.PO + "','" + order.Name + "','" + order.Company + "','" + order.Address + "','" + order.City + "','" + order.State + "','" + order.ZipCode + "','" + order.Country + "','" + order.Phone + "','" + order.Date + "','" + order.ShippingMethod + "','" + order.Notes + "')";
       foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
       {
        query = "insert into OrderItem values ('" + orderItem.PO + "','" + orderItem.StockNumber + "','" + orderItem.Quantity + "','" + orderItem.UnitPrice + "')";
       //Console.WriteLine(orderItem.ToJson());
       }
    }
```

I can access order.PO, order.Name , etc but I get error for orderItem like below:
[image]

The weird part is when I check `orderItem.ToJson()` I get the json fine like:

```
{"PO":"009723","StockNumber":"0040","Quantity":5,"UnitPrice":16.445000}
```

Which means I am getting the data but why is it giving me error when I try to access the data like orderItem.PO?

My class structure is like below if needed:

```
public class xmlOrder
{

    public string PO { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string ShippingMethod { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public ArrayList OrderItems { get; set; }

    public xmlOrder()
    {
        this.PO = string.Empty;
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Company = string.Empty;
        this.Address = string.Empty;
        this.City = string.Empty;
        this.State = string.Empty;
        this.ZipCode = string.Empty;
        this.Country = string.Empty;
        this.Phone = string.Empty;
        this.Date = string.Empty;
        this.ShippingMethod = string.Empty;
        this.Notes = string.Empty;
        this.OrderItems = new ArrayList();
    }
}

public class xmlOrderItem
{
    public string PO { get; set; }
    public string StockNumber { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public xmlOrderItem()
    {
        this.PO = string.Empty;
        this.StockNumber = string.Empty;
        this.Quantity = 0;
        this.UnitPrice = decimal.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`? Consider switching to `List<OrderItem>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add objects to arraylist and read them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275586/add-objects-to-arraylist-and-read-them)

Comment: @tukaef THANKS! used list instead of ArrayList and it worked :)

Comment: It is a duplicate because the issue is the same: when using `foreach` to enumerate an `ArrayList` you are unable to access members from a derived type because the iteration variable is of type `object`. Did you read the solution presented in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275731/150605) and try applying it to your code? It's the same idea as in @Jonathan's answer here. I see that changing from `ArrayList` to `List<>` solved your problem, which also happens to be the same solution proposed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275792/150605) on that question.

Comment: Also, there is no `ToJson()` method in your `xmlOrderItem` class, so it must be an [extension method](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).  It makes sense that a method that converts arbitrary objects to JSON would take an `object` parameter, therefore you could call that method on any variable of any type, including your variable `orderItem`.  Being able to call an `object` method (extension or otherwise) doesn't indicate anything about the compile-time type of a variable, which in this case is obscured by the use of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of your `items` object? You should show more of this method. If it's of type `object` you should try to make it a concrete object. You could also cast your `object`to your type as such:

```
foreach (var orderItem in order.OrderItems)
   {
      var item = orderItem as xmlOrderItem
      if (item == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("orderItem is not an xmlOrderItem")
      query = "insert into OrderItem values ('" + item .PO + "','" + item .StockNumber + "','" + item .Quantity + "','" + item .UnitPrice + "')";
   //Console.WriteLine(orderItem.ToJson());
   }
```